# Using username and password for KerberosRestTemplate

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-kerberos

How can I pass in kerberos username and password to the `KerberosRestTemplate` instead of passing keytab location or using validated cache. This works fine with plain spring security kerberos where for all rest calls the user passes the -u user:password param which is picked up by `SunJaasKerberosClient` to login.